# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" in pcl code when i try to come to Plane Model Segmentation

Tags: segmentation-fault, ros, point-cloud-library

there is a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when i try to make up Plane Model Segmentation with pcl.

this is a .cpp file which running in ubuntu16.04, CMake,  pcl-1.8,

```
    #include <pcl-1.8/pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
    #include <pcl-1.8/pcl/filters/impl/extract_indices.hpp>
    #include <pcl-1.8/pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
    #include <pcl-1.8/pcl/segmentation/impl/sac_segmentation.hpp>

    PCL_INSTANTIATE(SacSegmentationExtraction, PointXYZIT);

    void remove_wake(pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZIT>::Ptr in_filtered, pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZIT>::Ptr out_filtered)
    {
      pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
      pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);

      pcl::SACSegmentation<PointXYZIT> seg;
      seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
      seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
      seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);

      seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.2);
      seg.setInputCloud (in_filtered);
      seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);

      std::cerr << "Model coefficients: " << coefficients->values[0] << " " 
                                  << coefficients->values[1] << " "
                                  << coefficients->values[2] << " " 
                                  << coefficients->values[3] << std::endl;

      std::cerr << "Model inliers: " << inliers->indices.size () << std::endl;


      pcl::ExtractIndices<PointXYZIT> extract;
      extract.setInputCloud (in_filtered);
      extract.setIndices (inliers); 
      extract.setNegative (true);
      extract.filter (*out_filtered);
      pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII<PointXYZIT>("remove_plane.pcd", *out_filtered);
    }
```

that is the whole code,when i catkin_make it will be ok,but when i rosrun, it show the error:Segmentation fault (core dumped)
i think there isn't the null ptr in definations, and no multithread, no used string.and i don't know how to do.

Comment: Please post the stack frames. Segmentation fault should provide more detail. Debug using gdb would be the next step. Also check for `in_filtered == nullptr` and `out_filtered == nullptr`.

Comment: OK，thanks,i need do more work by myself.thanks a lot.